# another error faced when installing snorby on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bundler, delayed-job

When installing snorby, I need to use this line:

```
sudo bundle exec rake snorby:setup
```

When executing this, a problem occurred:

```
rake aborted!
There was an error while trying to load the gem 'delayed_job'.
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `yaml_as' for Module:Class
Did you mean?  yaml_tag
```

(PS: It is said that when using bundler, psych is used which prevents delayed_job from working properly)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.